# Changing the way my code prints out

Tags: java, formatting, string-formatting

I need help figuring out how to change the way my code prints out, I understand that it is going to do something dealing with

n, n-1, n-2,... etc for the spacing, but how do I do this so that I get this

```
        1
      2 1
    3 2 1
... 3 2 1
```

instead of this

```
  1
  1 2
  1 2 3
  1 2 3...
```

.

```js
//A program that displays the pattern of a number entered in increasing order

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisplayPattern  
{  
   public static void main(String ar[])  
   {
      //Initialize Scanner
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
      //Get user input/ start loop
      while (true)
      {
         //Receive user input
         System.out.println("Enter a positive integer to display pattern: ");
         int x = input.nextInt();
         
         //Show user output  
         displayPattern(x);
         
      //Continuation of loop
         System.out.println("Do you want to continue (Y/N)?");
         String s = input.nextLine();
         s = input.nextLine();
         s = s.toLowerCase();
         if (s.charAt(0) == 'n')
            break;
      }           
   }  
   
   public static void displayPattern(int n)  
   {
      //Create pyramid of numbers with increasing order  
      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)  
      {  
         for(int j=i;j>0;j--)  
         { 
               System.out.print(" "+j);  
         }  
            System.out.print("\n");  
      }  
   }  
}
```

Comment: The answer is simply to figure out how many spaces you want to display on each line, then write code to do that.  The number of spaces should follow a simple pattern so you should be able to figure out a simple algebraic formula that depends on `i` and `n`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could build your string first with something like `s = s + " " + j`.  Then when the whole string is built, look at `s.length()` and subtract the length from something in order to figure out how many spaces to print out before printing `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you create spaces for the numbers you are not printing first, so we always start the inner loop with the user input.

This should work for you:

```
public static void displayPattern(int n) {
    // Create pyramid of numbers with increasing order
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = n; j > 0; j--) {
            if (j > i) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" " + j);
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```